# LINQ Does not contain a definition for 'Key' and no extension method 'Key' accepting a first argument of type

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to LINQ. I have this code that is working

```
l.realtimed_graph = new[] { l.rtl[0].realtimed, l.rtl[1].realtimed, l.rtl[2].realtimed }.SelectMany(p => p).GroupBy(p => p.Key)
                  .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Max(p => p.Value));
```

now since I need to use unknow numbers of dictionary I modified the code to this

```
 l.realtimed_graph = new[] { l.rtl.ToArray() }.SelectMany(p => p).GroupBy(p => p.Key)
                      .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Max(p => p.Value));
```

and get error "does not contain a definition of 'Key" and no extension methid 'Key' accepting a first argument of type.

Comment: Without any mention of the types involved we can only guess, which is not that fun.

Comment: What is the type of `realtimed` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want:

```
 l.realtimed_graph = l.rtl.SelectMany(p => p.realtimed).GroupBy(p => p.Key)
                      .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Max(p => p.Value));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know the type and properties of your class, I created an example with `Tuple':

```
var dict = new List<IEnumerable<Tuple<string, int>>>
{
    new Tuple<string, int>[] {
        new Tuple<string, int>("a", 1)
    },
    new Tuple<string, int>[] {
        new Tuple<string, int>("b", 3),
        new Tuple<string, int>("a", 2),
        new Tuple<string, int>("a", 3),
    },
    new Tuple<string, int>[] {
        new Tuple<string, int>("b", 2),
        new Tuple<string, int>("c", 5),
        new Tuple<string, int>("b", 3),
        new Tuple<string, int>("c", 2),
        new Tuple<string, int>("c", 2),
        new Tuple<string, int>("a", 3)
    }
};

var grouped = dict.SelectMany(p => p).GroupBy(p => p.Item1);
// results in list of int values grouped by string value
// list of IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Tuple<string, int>>>
// a - 1, 2, 3, 3
// b - 3, 2, 3
// c - 5, 2, 2

var dict = grouped.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Max(p => p.Item2));
// results in simple dictionary: a - 3, b - 3, c - 5
```